# ShellScript not working on Pre-session-command (PowerCenter)

Tags: shell, informatica-powercenter

The goal is to check the existence of a file and create a blank file if this doesn't exist, using Shell Script on the Pre-session-command (Informatica PowerCenter) like the code below:

```
ParamDirTrabalho=/dir/powercenter/project1
ParamArq=file.csv

ParamQtdArq=`cat ${ParamDirTrabalho}/${ParamArq} | wc -l`

if [ $ParamQtdArq == 0 ];then touch ${ParamDirTrabalho}/${ParamArq};fi
```

This is the error:

*Message: [Pre/Post Session Command] Process id 10683. Standard output and error:
sh: line 2: 
: command not found
cat: /dir/powercenter/project1
/file.csv
: No such file or directory
sh: line 4: 
: command not found*

**I can execute successfully when pointing to a sh file with the code above. But I need to write the code inside the pre-session-command.**

Answer (score 0):

Please enclose parameters by double quotes.

- ParamDirTrabalho="/dir/powercenter/project1"
- ParamArq="file.csv"

Also pls make sure you provide RWX permission to folders.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the WC from a file if it doesn't exist at all. That's what the error is "No such file or directory" if I understand it right. What you need to do is check if file exists or not rather than the count and then touch if it doesn't exist.

```
if [ ! -f filename ];then touch filename; fi
```

or

```
if [ -f filename ];then exit 0; else touch filename; fi
```